# how to resolve the database schema for the following

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a table below which displays university which will have id and attributes ,Stream offered  will have more Streams added later. And subjects in each stream even that is dynamic .
Basically the fields and data within all will keep increasing .How do I create database schema where everything.Thanks in Advance.

Link to see the table :

http://tableizer.journalistopia.com/tableizer.php

```
 <style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
    border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>University</th><th>Stream</th><th>Branch</th><th>Courses</th><th>Subjects 2</th></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Science</td><td>Electronics</td><td>Signal processing</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Telecommunications engineering</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Control engineering</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Mechanical</td><td>Thermodynamics</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Mechatronics</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Computers</td><td>Microprocessor</td><td>Design Steps</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Performance</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Memory</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Network and Database Administration</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Digital Signal Processing</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Commerce</td><td>Accounting</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Business</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Advertising</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>ARTS</td><td>Event Management Courses</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Mass Communication Courses</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Fashion Design Courses</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont know how to create relationship table between all of them where everything is dynamic .I have created more of 1-many where customer is related to many tables and the fields are fixed but in the above example everything can change .So how do I design this? I really appreciate any help.Appreciate your time .Basically what should I be referring to resolve the above conundrum ?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Can you refer me to a tutorial for the above requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there will be a table for each column in your table, where they refer back to their parent, i.e. Stream Table will have a UniversityId column referring the University table, etc.  A bit simplistic, but a start.

Look at the below links for now:

- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/knowing-just-enough-about-relational-databases.html

and then:

- http://digitalethos.org/relational-database-design-a-best-practices-primer/

Good luck.